# Can I see the exact command that is been executed with project clean in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to see the exact command that eclipse excecutes for compile when I do a project clean. That is, the complete path to javac and the options used.

Thanks

Comment: `javac` compiles the code. How do you know it cleans? It's probably pure java code that deletes the `bin/` folder or all class files within

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't use javac, it has its own incremental compiler which is accessed using APIs not a command line.

Project clean will basically delete objects in the output folder as defined in the project properties. The Eclipse build system will then run to regenerate the output.

The clean uses the `IProject` `build` method with `IncrementalProjectBuilder.CLEAN_BUILD` as the build kind.

```
IProject project = ... selected project

project.build(IncrementalProjectBuilder.CLEAN_BUILD, progressMonitor);
```

exactly what happens depends on the builders which are registered for the particular project. Each builder can contribute to the clean up.